# How can I capture HTML, unmolested by the capturing library?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

Is there a Python library out there that will let me get an arbitrary HTML snippet *without* molesting the markup?  As far as I can tell, lxml, BeautifulSoup, and pyquery all make it easy to something like `soup.find(".arbitrary-class")`, but the HTML it returns is formatted.  I want the raw, original markup.

So for example, say I have this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="arbitrary-class">
      This is some<br />
      markup with <br>
      <p>some potentially problematic</p>
      stuff in it <input type="text" name="w00t">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to capture *exactly*:

```
"
      This is some<br />
      markup with <br>
      <p>some potentially problematic</p>
      stuff in it <input type="text" name="w00t">
    "
```

...spaces and all, and without mangling the tags to be properly formatted (as `<br />` for example).

The trouble, it seems is that all 3 libraries appear to construct the DOM internally and simply return a Python object representing what the file *should* be rather than what it *is*, so I don't know where/how to get the original code snippet I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("index.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html.parser")
    print soup.select(".arbitrary-class")[0].contents
```

will return you the list:

```
[u'\n      This is some', <br/>, u'\n      markup with ', <br/>, u'\n', <p>some potentially problematic</p>, u'\n      stuff in it ', <input name="w00t" type="text"/>, u'\n']
```

EDIT:

As Daniel noted in the comments, this results in normalized tags.

The only alternative I can find is to use a parser generator, such as pyparsing. The code below is a slight modification to some of their [example code](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing-module.html#withAttribute) for the `withAttribute` function.

```
from pyparsing import *

html = """<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="arbitrary-class">
    This is some<br />
    markup with <br>
    <p>some potentially problematic</p>
    stuff in it <input type="text" name="w00t">
    </div>
</body>
</html>"""

div,div_end = makeHTMLTags("div")

# only match div tag having a class attribute with value "arbitrary-class"
div_grid = div().setParseAction(withClass("arbitrary-class"))
grid_expr = div_grid + SkipTo(div | div_end)("body")
for grid_header in grid_expr.searchString(html):
    print repr(grid_header.body)
```

The output from this code is as follows:

```
'\n    This is some<br />\n    markup with <br>\n    <p>some potentially problematic</p>\n    stuff in it <input type="text" name="w00t">'
```

Note that the first `<br/>` now has a space, and the `<input>` tag no longer has an added / before the closing >. The only difference from your specification is that the trailing white space is missing. You might be able to resolve this difference by refining this solution.

Comment: This modified the markup though.  Note the first `<br/>` is lacking the space, and the `<input>` tag has an added `/` just before the closing `>`.

Comment: @Daniel please mark my answer as Accepted if you are happy with the edited version. Thanks